# React : Script 'Failed to compile' using componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs, lightgallery

**Setup**

I've loaded the Vanilla JS library lightgallery.js through NPM and `importing` it as normal.

**Issue**

I'm initializing this library through `componentDidMount()`, but it's failing to compile because `'lightGallery' is not defined`. *see sample below*

I verified the library is importing by removing `componentDidMount()` and initializing it through the Chrome Console.  When I do this, it works as intended.

I'm not clear on why it's resulting in `'lightGallery' is not defined` when the import clearly works when i don't initialize it with `componentDidMount()`.  I'm guessing it's either an issue with the elements not being present in the `DOM` at load or it's an issue with the way my `import` is setup.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Current Page**

*This is a stripped down version of my setup with the gallery elements hardcoded for easy explanation.*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'lightgallery.js';

class Gallery extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'));
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <>
                <section>
                    <h1>Gallery</h1>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <div id="lightgallery">
                        <a href="img/img1.jpg">
                            <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="img/img2.jpg">
                            <img src="img/thumb2.jpg" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="img/img3.jpg">
                            <img src="img/thumb3.jpg" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </>
        ); 
    }
}

export default Gallery;
```

Comment: is it putting it on `window` maybe? try `window.lightGallery`

Comment: I'm at a loss for words why I didn't think to do that.  That solved it.  Thanks!